# Extracting values computed within a Manipulate environment

Tags: graphics, manipulate, vector

I use this [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html):

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{{Blue, Circle[]},
        {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, pt}]}, {Red, InfiniteLine[pt, Cross[pt]]}},
        Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3/2],
        {{pt, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> ((pt = Normalize[#]) &)}]
```

`pt` will be a pair of values {pntx, pnty}.

How can I get `pntx` or `pntx`?

Comment: There's a + button in the upper left.  Click on it and select "Paste Snapshot" from the popup menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always store the value in other symbol.

```
Manipulate[
 pntx = First[pt];
 pnty = Last[pt];
 Graphics[{{Blue, Circle[]}, {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, pt}]}, {Red, 
    InfiniteLine[pt, Cross[pt]]}}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> 3/2], {{pt, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> ((pt = Normalize[#]) &)}]
```

Now `pntx` and `pnty` contains the individual coordinate values, which are normalised by your [`TrackingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) .

```
Norm[{pntx, pnty}]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

other alternatives:

```
{pntx, pnty} = pt;

pntx = Part[pt,1];
```